# wp_redirect() function is not working

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

`wp_redirect($post->guid)` is not working. How can I fix this?

This is my code:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['vid']) ){

    $id=$_REQUEST['vid'];

    $post_title = 'sasa';

    $post_content ='zxczxczxc';

    $new_post = array(
      'ID' => '',
      'post_author' => $user->ID, 
      'post_content' => $post_content,
      'post_title' => $post_title,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      // NOW IT'S ALREADY AN ARRAY

    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

    // This will redirect you to the newly created post
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    $url=$post->guid;

    wp_redirect($post->guid);

}
```

Answer (score 29):

Two things wrong here:

1. Don't use `$post->guid` as an url
2. You **must** `exit()` after using  `wp_redirect()` ([see the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect))

> `wp_redirect()` does not exit automatically and should almost always be followed by exit. 
>   
>   To redirect to your new post's page:

```
//..... code as in question
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
$url = get_permalink( $post_id );
wp_redirect($url);
exit();
```

Comment: Beat you by 30 seconds :D

Comment: this is not working, if i run the page console show 302 Found
  479ms 
jquery...r=1.7.1 (line 4)
GET http://localhost/wordpress/newpages-17/
 
200 OK
  1.2s loading..........

Comment: Thats a JS error. Nothing to do with `wp_redirect`. The above answer is the correct way to do it, so you must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: sorry.it show only GET localhost/wordpress/newpages-17 200 OK 1.2s loading..........

Comment: @StephenHarris would you mind looking over my redirect question at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/76991/10413 I've also tried your code from this answer using $pid but still can't get it to work. Thanks

Comment: This question gets a huge number of views, so please consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem.  That way the question shows up as answered and helps us keep the site tidy.  Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

I have a simple solution, please read:

1. If you are using `wp_redirect($url)` in theme files, and it is not working add `ob_clean() ob_start()` in your function file on top.
2. If using in plugin add `ob_clean() ob_start()` in the main plugin file on top.

And make sure you have added `exit() function after wp_redirect($url)` Like this:

```
$url = 'http://example.com';
wp_redirect($url);
exit();
```

Comment: This solves the issue with Mozilla Firefox returning 200 instead of 302 for the redirection to take place. Chrome redirects while Firefox doesn't. This fix helps. Thank you!

Comment: This is a more detailed answer if you are creating a plugin or designing template. worked for me.

Comment: I've been struggling to make this work in my custom theme... Works like a charm...

Comment: Note, that as mentioned in another answer, that on templates you need to do the login check and redirect before the 'get_header()' function, or put your login check function n the add_filter('init','mylogincheck') in your template. Otherwise, there will be a 'headers already sent' error that might not show up in your error log (depending on error settings).

Comment: Worked! Out of courtesy to other developers make sure to call `ob_clean` a second time.  `ob_clean();ob_start(); /*plugin code*/ ob_clean();`

Comment: If using in plugin add ob_clean() ob_start() in the main plugin file on top this code only work for me.

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure if this will help... but I found that I had some code in a template
and I was starting with get_header() in this way:

```
<?php
/**
 * .. Template comments
 */

 get_header();

 if(...) {
    ...
    if(...) {
      ...
      wp_redirect($url);
      exit();
    }
 }
 ?>
```

and was getting the same issue of header previously sent... What I did was just move get_header() to the end of the block and voila!!!

```
<?php
/**
 * .. Template comments
 */


 if(...) {
    ...
    if(...) {
      ...
      wp_redirect($url);
      exit();
    }
 }
 get_header();
 ?>
```

No plugin was disabled. and everything was ok... you may give a try if this works for you

Comment: This is a good way to do it, if you have access to the theme source. Redirects should run before the call to `get_header`.

Comment: removing get_header() also worked for me!

Comment: I'd bet this is the most common cause for most people struggling with `wp_redirect` not working

Answer (score 5):

Never ever use the post GUID value, it does not have to match the real URL of the post.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Important_GUID_Note

```
wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post_id ) );
exit(); // always exit
```

Also, make sure `wp_redirect` is not plugged by something else which prevents it from doing its job correctly. Deactivate all plugins and revert to Twenty Ten/Eleven to check.

Comment: +1 good call on `wp_redirect` being pluggable

Comment: thaning you....

Answer (score 3):

I had same problems here,
I just try any method like

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_function_name'); or add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_function_name'); but it's not working
```

finally i got hook that can work with perfectly redirect,
below my full code in **functions.php**

```
function redirect_homepage(){
    ob_clean();
    ob_start();
    $args = array(
        'public'   => true,
        '_builtin' => false,
     );
    
     $output = 'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
     $operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
    
     $post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator ); 
        if(is_singular($post_types)){

            $url = get_bloginfo('url');
            wp_redirect($url, '301');
            exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_homepage');
```

just use hook **add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_function_name');**

**Nb: i use child-theme**

Comment: Thanks a LOT!  Tried many combination with wp_redirect, exit, die, header. Help ob_clean(); ob_start(); at frst!

Answer (score 1):

header already sent is main reason. As header already sent, so its unable to resend it and fails to redirect. Use before header like in init hook.

```php
add_action('init', 'your_app_function');
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have: `get_header();` or any wordpress function that potentially creates contents like header and footer in your template. Otherwise the redirection won't work.

Some developers try to clear the page by using `ob_start();` but if you have content in your page even if you use `ob_start();` the redirection won't work.

and then simply try this code:

```
wp_redirect(get_permalink($post->ID));
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( is_page( ['wfp-dashboard', 'wfp-checkout'] ) ){
   if(!is_user_logged_in()){
      @ob_flush();
      @ob_end_flush();
      @ob_end_clean();
      wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
      exit();
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you include some explanation of how this fixes the issue? I'm not sure why there are output buffers in the code, and they have the `@` operator, `@` doesn't prevent errors from happening, it just hides them from the error log

Answer (score 0):

Just noted that W3 total cache plugin must be active for this to work.  It disabled mine for some reason.

```php
wp_redirect("/");
exit;
```