# wp_redirect "headers already sent" after front-end submission form

Tags: wp-redirect

I'm trying to practice with setting up a front-end post submission form.  And I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/sadlight/public_html/members/wp-content/themes/default-child/announcement-submit.php:1) in /home/sadlight/public_html/members/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 876
```

announcement-submit.php is my template below.

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381661/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by-wordpress-issue), but no go.

Also, when I use wp_redirect in my code below, it inserts TWO posts instead of one.  When I remove it, it only enters one.  Any help would be great!

Just for extra info: I'm using buddypress with the default buddypress theme.

```
<?php

/*
 * Template Name: Announcement Submit
  */

$postTitleError = '';
if ( isset( $_POST['submitted'] ) ) {
    if ( trim( $_POST['postTitle'] ) === '' ) {
        $postTitleError = 'Please enter a title.';
        $hasError = true;
    }
}


get_header(); ?>

    <div id="content">
        <div class="padder">

            <form action="" id="primaryPostForm" method="POST">
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="postTitle"><?php _e('Post Title:', 'framework') ?></label>
                    <input type="text" name="postTitle" id="postTitle" class="required" value="<?php if ( isset( $_POST['postTitle'] ) ) echo esc_attr( stripslashes( $_POST['postTitle'] ) ); ?>" />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <?php wp_editor( 'Testing some content', 'postcontent'); ?>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'post_nonce', 'post_nonce_field' ); ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                    <button type="submit"><?php _e('Add Post', 'framework') ?></button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>

            <?php if ( $postTitleError != '' ) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $postTitleError; ?></span>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php
                if ( isset( $_POST['submitted'] ) && isset( $_POST['post_nonce_field'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['post_nonce_field'], 'post_nonce' ) ) {
                    if ( trim( $_POST['postTitle'] ) === '' ) {
                        $postTitleError = 'Please enter a title.';
                        $hasError = true;
                    }
                    $post_information = array(
                        'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['postTitle'] ),
                        'post_content' => wp_kses_post( $_POST['postcontent'] ),
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'post_status' => 'pending'                                      
                    );
                    wp_insert_post( $post_information );                    
                }

                $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_information );

                if ( $post_id ) {
                    wp_redirect( home_url() );
                    exit;                   
                }
            ?>

        </div><!-- .padder -->
    </div><!-- #content -->

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Check this answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/76993/10413

Comment: Thanks for your response.  That took care of the error, but it didn't add the post. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Otto pointed out, you're sending data to the browser before calling `wp_redirect()`.

- `get_header()` will output the page's HTML `<head>`
- You're printing the entire form to the page before processing it.

To fix the "headers already sent" issue, you need to move all of your form processing from the bottom of the page to the top of the page.  If you need to call `wp_redirect()` you must make that call ***before*** you print anything - HTML or anything else - to the page.

As for the duplicate post entry, you have `wp_insert_post()` twice in your code:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submitted'] ) && isset( $_POST['post_nonce_field'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['post_nonce_field'], 'post_nonce' ) ) {
    if ( trim( $_POST['postTitle'] ) === '' ) {
        $postTitleError = 'Please enter a title.';
        $hasError = true;
    }
    $post_information = array(
        'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['postTitle'] ),
        'post_content' => wp_kses_post( $_POST['postcontent'] ),
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'pending'                                      
    );
    wp_insert_post( $post_information );                    
}

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_information );
```

So you're attempting to insert a post *on every page load* but if nothing has been submitted the `$post_information` variable won't be set and nothing gets inserted.  However, when you submit the form you're creating a new post both inside the bool check *and* outside the bool check.

Comment: In addition, it would be better to move the entire form processing into your functions file and hook into some action like `template_redirect`, where you are sure nothing has been sent to the browser yet.

Comment: Thanks! This is something that I'd rather do to keep things separate.  However, I've been searching for the past hour trying to get a better understanding of how to use template_redirect or what it actually does. I'm dumbfounded.

Comment: Well, I separated it. And it worked!  I'll make the $_POST names unique so they won't clash with anything else.

Answer (score 3):

> headers already sent by (output started at
>   /home/sadlight/public_html/members/wp-content/themes/default-child/announcement-submit.php:1)

The error message tells you exactly what you need to know.

The "announcement-submit.php" is where the problem is.

The "1" is the line number of the problem.

So, you actually have something before your initial `<?php` line that is causing output. A blank line, perhaps. Or the UTF-8 BOM, perhaps.

Load the file in a plain text editor. Nothing fancy. Notepad, perhaps. Or VIM. Make sure nothing exists before that starting PHP tag. Save the file. Or, in your editor of choice, check the save options and make sure it's not set to save a BOM (Byte-Order-Marker) at the beginning of the file.

Comment: it's more than just space before the opening `<?php`, there's the whole `get_header` and all the markup output before the `wp_redirect` line half-way down the template.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried what you suggested with just using notepad.  I even ensured Notepad++ (my code editor) was saving UTF-8 without BOM.  Re-uploaded the file... and now I have this error: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/sadlight/public_html/members/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/header.php:2) in /home/sadlight/public_html/members/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 876`   .... Line 2 of header.php is `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>`

Comment: @Milo I removed all white space that I could that made sense... inbetween lines and after lines.  Same error.

Comment: There should be absolutely nothing at all before that initial php line. No space, no text, no code.

Answer (score 0):

This can have multiple causes. The headers can only be send when there is no output before it. And with output I mean *any* output. So no whitespaces before the PHP opening tags, no `echo`s no BOM characters.

Basically that error message tells you exactly where the output is started so that is where one of above things is happening.

For a complete list of things you should check and also how to prevent this error please see this fine [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/508666).