# wp_redirect() - headers already sent

Tags: theme-development, headers, wp-redirect

I am trying to use `wp_redirect()` to redirect the user after successfully submitting a signup form on the page.

It's not working and shows the following error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/theme/wp-content/themes/test/header.php:10)
>   in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/theme/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line
>   1178

I understand there has been already output before, that's why it's not working, but I have no clue how to make this work.

The signup form gets rendered by a function, and is submitted by another function, inside my functions.php.

```
if ( isset( $_POST['subscribe'] ) ) {
    // Submits the form and should then redirect
    wp_redirect("/thank-you/");
    exit;
}
```

Then both these functions are used where I want to show the signup form.

I'm afraid that's not the best thing to do. I should be creating some action that does that, but I have no idea how to implement that. Most of the tutorials I found show the results directly on the same page and don't require an additional redirect. Maybe that's why they are working with functions inside the functions.php

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found the answer [(via)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76991/wp-redirect-not-working-after-submitting-form/76993#76993)

Instead of using the function directly, I added an action to "wp_loaded", that makes sure that it gets loaded before any headers are sent.

```
<?php
add_action ('wp_loaded', 'my_custom_redirect');
function my_custom_redirect() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['subscribe'] ) ) {
        $redirect = 'http://example.com/redirect-example-url.html';
        wp_redirect($redirect);
        exit;
    }
}     
?>
```

Comment: It got rid of the error but the post did not save!

Answer (score 13):

You have to use `wp_redirect()`
before `get_header()`
Then it will not show header error.

Answer (score 6):

you can also do this

Instead of the below line

wp_redirect("$url");

write

```
echo("<script>location.href = '".$url."'</script>");
```

or

```
<?php <script><?php echo("location.href = '".$url."';");?></script>?>
```

It'll definitely solve your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot man !

Comment: your welcome...@MarcoFloriano

Answer (score 3):

```
add_action('template_redirect', function(){
if(isset($_POST['subscriptio'])){// make this condition such that it only matches when a registraiotn form get submitted
/**
 * do your stuff here
 */
wp_redirect();//....
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that code didn't worked for me. Needed to add the action to "wp_loaded" to get it worked (See my answer)

Comment: Works well if you need to establish `is_page_template()` when conditionally redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a plugin, you can call `ob_start();`  at the beginning of the plugin code or `ob_start();` at the top of the functions.php file before code begins

[image]